# PHP 7 and Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, php7

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and just tried to update from PHP 5.6 to 7 - everything worked fine and when I type in

```
php -v
```

I get this

```
PHP 7.0.5-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I restarted my apache with `service apache2 restart` and it did too. But I can´t access the php version. Maybe I was using the mod_php before instead of the cli/cgi but I am not able to find something about `change php version on apache` anywhere on google etc.

My PHP7 lays in `/etc/php/7.0`  with

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 27 19:56 cli
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr 27 19:56 fpm
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 27 19:56 mods-available
```

My info.php with phpinfo(); is not getting executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if he module is enable in apache in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

Comment: @Dom which module?

Comment: you're missing `mod_php`, did you compile php or did you use package?

Comment: @alexus I used this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04 Tutorial, so I guess packages

Comment: @isengo tutorial covers `nginx` and not `apache2`...

Comment: @alexus it says 'Upgrading mod_php with Apache' Anyhow, since I get the php -v for PHP7, what module do I ahve to install? It seems that apache doenst know yet to use PHP7

Here is my installation process http://www.beetxt.com/hkq/

Comment: `apache` usually use `mod_php`, while `nginx` `php-fpm`.

Comment: ATM under mods-enabled is only php5.conf and php5.load